# How i can check that one word exist in between 2 range or words?

Tags: java, android, search

I want to check in java that one word like "fga" exist between "abc" and "lmp" or not.
for this example my word range starts from "fga" "fgb" "fbc"... "lmo" "lmp". i cannot use contain or substring becuase i have to found these in between, like First word is "fga" and second is "xyz", now a word "lac" lies between ,so i have to check programmtically that it lies between them or not.

First word is **"abc"** and second is **"fgh"**, now if my search word is "**dee**" then return true. from first word to second word ("abc" "abd" "abe".. "abz" "aca" "acb"... "fgg" "fgh") if my word exist then it will return true. i dont have a string where all these word contain. i have only 2 words and a search word
now i want to check my search word exist in these range or not.

I tried with loop but its a long process

```
{
        char firstLetter = firstWord[0];
        char secondLetter = firstWord[1];
        char thirdLetter = firstWord[2];

        char i = 'a', j = 'a', k = 'a';


        do
        {
            for (i = firstLetter; i <= 'z'; i++)
            {
                for (j = secondLetter; j <= 'z'; j++)
                {
                    for (k = thirdLetter; k <= 'z'; k++)
                    {
                        if (k == secondWord[2])
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        if (!foundOnPage && text.equalsIgnoreCase("" + i + "" + j + "" + k))
                        {
                            foundOnPage = true;
                            pageNo = WordPageNo;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    thirdLetter = 'a';
                    if (j == secondWord[1])
                        break;
                    if (foundOnPage)
                        break;
                }
                secondLetter = 'a';

                if (i == secondWord[0] || foundOnPage)
                    break;
            }
            firstLetter = 'a';
            if (foundOnPage)
                break;
        }
        while ((String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j) + String.valueOf(k)).equalsIgnoreCase(secondWord.toString()) || !foundOnPage);

    }
```

Comment: and this far you have tried...? Show us some of your code!

Comment: Hint: lookup `String.contains()` and `String.subString()`. That's all you'll need to solve your riddle.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

```
String sourceString = "fga fgb fbc... lmo lmp";
String beginWord = "abc";
String endWord =  "lmp";
String keyWord = "fga";
int ixBegin = sourceString.indexOf(beginWord);
int ixEnd = sourceString.indexOf(endWord);
int ixKey = sourceString.indexOf(keyWord);

if (ixKey > ixBegin && ixKey < ixEnd) {
    // do your magic here
}
```

Or You can split source string to words and analyze position of "keyWord" in words array. Or do something else: there are many ways to do that...

**Update**

Anyway You can "manually" implement `indexOf()/pos()/substring()` methods or do someting like that:

```
String sourceString = "fga fgb fbc... lmo lmp";
String beginWord = "abc";
String endWord =  "lmp";
String keyWord = "fga";
char currSourceChar;
int ixCharBeginWord = 0;
int posBeginWord = -1;
int ixCharEndWord = 0;
int posEndWord = -1;
int ixCharKeyWord = 0;
int posKeyWord = -1;

for (int ixChar = 0; ixChar < sourceString.length(); ixChar++) {
  currSourceChar = sourceString.charAt(ixChar);

  // found pos of "beginWord" 
  if (currSourceChar == beginWord.charAt(ixCharBeginWord)) {
    ixCharBeginWord++;
  } else {
    ixCharBeginWord = 0;
  }

  if (ixCharBeginWord == beginWord.length() && ixChar < sourceString.length()-1 && sourceString.charAt(ixChar+1) == 0x20) {
      posBeginWord = ixChar - beginWord.length();  
  }

  // same way as above found pos of "endWord"

  // found as above  pos of "endWord" 

}

if (posKeyWord > posBeginWord && posKeyWord < posEndWord ) {
    // do your magic here
}
```

But it's useless.

Comment: just edited my qusetion. i dont want substring or indexof. i want to check whether a word like "cng" lies btween "abc" and "agf". character by character

Comment: @user3332319 Why do you want to go character by character? You need to explain your requirement better. (add examples of string inputs and results).

Comment: e.g first word is "abc" and second is "fgh", now if my search word is "dee" then return true. from first word to second word ("abc" "abd" "abe".. "abz"  "aca" "acb"... "fgg" "fgh") if my word exist then it will return true. i dont have a string where all these word contain. i have only 2 words and a search word

Comment: See updated answer, but seems it is an educational task and You should solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple Java solution:

```
String input = "fga fgb fgc"; //Your long string
if(input.contains("fga"))
{
 //When true do that
} else
{
  //Else do that
}
```